# SQL Programming in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

About Reporting Service:

Here is my Query Code, and Result Return.

As you can see, at the same `"DateTime"` I have three values are `"BATCH_NAME", "START_TIME",` and `"END_TIME",` but it not order in row.

So please help me delete all elements that null value.

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks all.

Here is my image:

http://upanh.biz/images/2014/08/22/untitledNzblm.png

http://upanh.biz/images/2014/08/22/untitledJ23t5.png

Comment: Could you please tell us the structure of your tables EventHistory, StringSnapshot and SnapshotTag? I think your problem is solveable with a group by.

Comment: Can u show me the way how to solve it? The EventHistory Table, StringSnapshot Table and SnapshotTag is linked via keylock. So plz tell me what Group By Command can do? Thanks in advance

Comment: try using `coalesce`

Answer (score 0):

Still hard to help you without knowing the actual tables and data, but I will give it a try.
I think you need to join StringSnapshot and SnapshotTag 3 times, because there are 3 different values you are looking for.

try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Hist.DateTime,
    BatchName = StringSnapshotBatchName.Value,
    StartTime= ...,
    EndTime= ...,
FROM
    EventHistory Hist
JOIN StringSnapshot StringSnapshotBatchName 
        ON StringSnapshotBatchName.EventLogKey= Hist.EventLogKey
        JOIN SnapshotTag SnapshotTagBatchName 
            ON SnapshotTagBatchName.SnapshotTagKey = StringSnapshotBatchName.SnapshotTagKey
            AND SnapshotTagBatchName.TagName = 'BATCH_NAME'
 JOIN StringSnapshot StringSnapshotStartTime 
        ON StringSnapshotStartTime .EventLogKey= Hist.EventLogKey
        JOIN SnapshotTag SnapshotTagStartTime 
            ON SnapshotTagStartTime .SnapshotTagKey = StringSnapshotStartTime .SnapshotTagKey
            AND SnapshotTagStartTime .TagName = 'START_TIME'
JOIN....
```